# How to generate a graph from a SMILES molecule representation?

Tags: python, rdkit, cheminformatics

I have a dataset of molecules represented with SMILES strings. I was trying to represent this as graphs. Is there a way to do so? For instance, let's say I have string `CC(C)(C)c1ccc2occ(CC(=O)Nc3ccccc3F)c2c1`, is there a general way to convert this to a graph representation, meaning adjacency matrix and atom vector? I see questions addressing [SMILES from graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195392/smiles-from-graph) and I know `rdkit` has `MolFromSmiles`, but I can't find something to get graph from SMILES string.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43299/is-there-a-way-to-use-free-software-to-convert-smiles-strings-to-structures ?

Comment: It looks like this only gives an image of the molecule. I came across Open Babel earlier, but searching the word graph gives nothing at its wiki page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try [pysmiles](https://github.com/pckroon/pysmiles).
Starting from the SMILES description you should be able to create a NetworkX graph and generate the desired objects with code along the lines of

```py
from pysmiles import read_smiles
import networkx as nx
    
smiles = 'C12=C3C4=C5C6=C1C7=C8C9=C1C%10=C%11C(=C29)C3=C2C3=C4C4=C5C5=C9C6=C7C6=C7C8=C1C1=C8C%10=C%10C%11=C2C2=C3C3=C4C4=C5C5=C%11C%12=C(C6=C95)C7=C1C1=C%12C5=C%11C4=C3C3=C5C(=C81)C%10=C23'
mol = read_smiles(smiles)
    
# atom vector (C only)
print(mol.nodes(data='element'))
# adjacency matrix
print(nx.to_numpy_matrix(mol))
```

If you can accept a so-so visualization, you can also tentatively plot the molecule with

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
elements = nx.get_node_attributes(mol, name = "element")
nx.draw(mol, with_labels=True, labels = elements, pos=nx.spring_layout(mol))
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

Fullerenes are fun to plot :)

[image: FullereneNetworkX]

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the output for this adjacency matrix does not defer between single/double/triple bonds. Is there a way to enforce that?

Comment: Ah, see your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066525/4240413 :)

Answer (score 7):

To complete Davide's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57063988/4240413, you can include the bond order to adjacency matrix using:

```
nx.to_numpy_matrix(mol, weight='order')
```

or according to [networkx documentation](https://testfixsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html) using

```
nx.adjacency_matrix(mol, weight='order').todense()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rdkit`'s `Chem.GetAdjacencyMatrix()`:

```py
from rdkit import Chem
import networkx as nx

smiles = 'CC(C)(C)c1ccc2occ(CC(=O)Nc3ccccc3F)c2c1'
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)

# Get adjacency matrix
adjacency_matrix = Chem.GetAdjacencyMatrix(mol, useBO = True)

# Convert adjacency matrix to NetworkX graph
G = nx.from_numpy_array(adjacency_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

`networkx` is a nice solution. If you are looking for something more custom, you can create the graph yourself. See example going in the other direction (SMILES from graph) in this post: [SMILES from graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195392/smiles-from-graph)

Comment: The OP actually wants the opposite of what you are suggesting. The OP wants SMILES **to** graph. He/she already has SMILES.

Comment: Yes true, have clarified that my answer is in the other direction. The link in the post mentioned leads you to SMILES -> graph though so imo the downvote is harsh (https://github.com/dakoner/keras-molecules/blob/dbbb790e74e406faa70b13e8be8104d9e938eba2/convert_rdkit_to_networkx.py#L65-L67)